# Right recursive grammar or left recursive?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, markup

I have little to no knowledge of what I'm about to ask, so I would like a suggestion based on the level of skills required to implemented a parser for the given grammar ( since I'm a beginner in this kind of formal approach to parsers and languages ).

Just by going back of a couple of years, this situation reminds me a little of Pascal grammar vs C/C++ grammar, this left vs right stuff.

But I'm not going to do any of that, my purpose is to implement a simple parser for a markup language for documents like Markdown.

So considering that I'm starting with a markup language in mind, I want to keep things simple, which is the easiest one to handle between this 2 options and why . Another kind of grammar could be an easier option for me ? If yes which one do you suggest ?

Answer (score 5):

Right recursive vs. left recursive mostly comes down to how you're going to implement the parser.

If you're going to do a top-down (e.g., recursive descent) parser, you normally want to use right recursion in the grammar (and for pure recursive descent, that's the only option).

If you're going to do a bottom-up parser, you normally want to use left recursion. Bottom up parsers are normally generated with a parser generator like Yacc or Bison, most of which *can* handle right recursion if needed, but can handle left recursion more efficiently, so it's preferred as long as it doesn't adversely affect semantics.

Comment: could you assign a specific spot to PEG grammars ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar ) ? I mean if I'm going to write a parser for a PEG I can assume that something will work better than other options ? I can cut down the options to a smaller number or a more specific area ?

Comment: @user2485710: Sorry, but offhand I'm really not sure.

Comment: PEGs require no left-recursion (as with LL grammars), though there are some implementations that can deal with it basically by transforming the grammar into a non-left-recursive form.  Since PEGs allow */+ closure directly, the problem of wanting left recursion for left associative operations is less important than with LL grammars

Comment: @ChrisDodd at the cost of being slightly OT, can you name a good parser generator in C/C++ for a PEG grammar ? I would like to have a reference to use as a starting point to formally define what I'm talking about here.

Comment: @user2485710: [boost::spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) uses PEG grammars/parsing for its parser generator

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon what type of parser you are using. If you use an LL type, you have to use right recursion.

If you use an LR type, you can use either left or right recursion. However, left recursion minimizes stack depth.

Comment: what do you mean with "type of parser" how many types of parser exist ?

Comment: Many types of parsers exist. The two main groups are LL and LR. They have subgroups like LR(1), LALR(1).

Comment: so that's why a Pascal compiler uses less memory and a C++ compiler typically requires more memory ? How about the implementation and how hard is to implement the given parser ?

Comment: Also, assuming that my grammar is a PEG grammar, what kind of parsers can meet my requirements ?

Comment: No, it isn't why a Pascal compiler uses less memory. That's because Pascal is a much simpler language, and also has a cleanly defined syntax. Pascal vs C++ has nothing to do with left vs right recursion.

Comment: @EJP I was remembering that Pascal declarations look like the "opposite" as in C++ and viceversa, that kind of left and right. I'll need to study this some more apparently .

Comment: 'That kind of left and right' is about the language itself. Your question is about grammars, in places where you have a choice of left or right recursion: for example, expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are two basic types of grammars:

```
LL(k) = Left to tight, leftmost derivation, k symbols look ahead
LR(k) = Left to right, rightmost derivation, k symbols look ahead
```

LR parsers are much more difficult to write by hand, however, they are more powerful then LL parsers. If you are looking at some popular parser generator tools:

```
ANTLR : a LL parser
BISON:  a LALR(1) parser (a type of LR parser but a bit less powerful)
CUP:    a LALR(1) parser (outputs Java / C# code)
```

Comment: thanks, I already have some names for already available parsers or libraries and tools that can generate a parser. My real problem now is that PEG grammars do not seem to be that popular and for example I can't find a bison or antlr equivalent for a PEG grammar, maybe it's just me getting something wrong or this grammars are not that popular as left or right grammars.

Comment: Well I have only worked with CUP and Bison so far and managed to write a pascal compiler so this things are quite powerfull. IMHO, a good lexer (flex hint hint) and a good parser generator will satisfy your every need when it comes to creating new languages in a robust way:)

Comment: Note that LL(k) is a subset of LR(k) -- all LL(k) grammars are LR(k).  In addition, while a grammar describes a language, there are many grammars that describe any given language.  Just because a grammar is not LL(k) (or LR(k)) does not mean that there is not a simpler grammar for the same language that is LL(k) (or LR(k))